# MvxAndroidApplication could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've successfully followed the "getting started" tutorial for MvvmCross. However, when I tried to create a new project on another computer, following that tutorial as a guide, I could not get it to compile. The "Core" project (the netstandard library) is fine; but when I create a new Xamarin Android project and I define `MainApplication` (which should inherit from `MvxAndroidApplication<MvxAndroidSetup<App>, App>`), the two Mvx names cannot be found.

Of course, I've followed very carefully all the instructions of the official tutorial, which means that I've installed the most recent (6.0.1) version of MvvmCross with NuGet. I have cleaned it and rebuilt it. I even explored the MvvmCross assembly that gets included, but it completely lacks the `MvvmCross.Platforms` namespace that should contain the two classes that I mentioned above.

It seems obvious to me that something is missing or misconfigured in the second computer. I have no idea what, though. One thing that caught my eye is that if I try to add a reference to `Mono.Android` it is listed as version 0.0.0.0.

How could I fix the issue? What should I check that I may have missed?

Comment: Could you build and run a xamarin android project in the second computer?

Comment: @Billy Yes I can. I may have found the cause: as soon as I can test it out, I'll post an answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself. It involves one undocumented requirement and one weird behaviour of Visual Studio (it certainly has a good reason, but I don't know what it is), so I'm leaving this here for reference.

**To use MvvmCross in a Xamarin Android project, you must target (Mono)Android 8.1.** I'm not sure whether that translates to "the most recent Android version" or if 8.1 has something special. Anyway, the NuGet package for MvvmCross includes the relevant DLL for the `monoandroid81` target: if your project is compiled for something else (even Mono Android 8.0), then NuGet will add the reference for `netstandard20`, and that DLL of course does not include anything in the `Platforms` namespace.

Once you have changed the build destination in the project settings, **you must at least unload and reload the project**. Or you can close the solution, but the project is really all that's needed. **This step is necessary** to get the correct target platform in Visual Studio. To cross-check it, open the `Add reference` window, and browse the "Framework" listing: at the top of the assembly list you'll find a label showing what is the current target platform. That label must show "MonoAndroid 8.1"; if it doesn't, check the project settings and then reload the project.

Comment: To target 8.1: droid.csproj -> properties -> Application -> "Compile using Android Version" -> choose Android 8.1.
If it isnt listed go ahead and update visual studio. For me using sdk manager didn't update the combobox choices.

Comment: @Offa Again, you must use the SDK Manager updater, **then reload the project**.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't help, anyone else has an idea on how to solve this issue? It happened after the update of MvvmCross from v5.6.3 to v6.1.2.
I changed the inheritence from Setup.cs to `MvxAppCompatApplication<MvxAppCompat<App>,App>` and needed to install the `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat` nuget package for that, yet it gives me this error.

Comment: Upgrading Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (from 27.x.x.x to 28.0.0.3) fixed the issue for me and I can use MvxAndroidApplication as stated in the tutorial. It is totally weird to me that you can't find a type in MvvmCross because of this, I'm new to NuGet and I have no idea what magic goes on behind the curtains.